# Aura method is not calling on checkbox click i tried with onclick and onchange both method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

MY cmp file code below

```
<div class="slds-p-around_small slds-grid slds-gutters">
           
            <lightning:input class="chkboxPadding" type="checkbox"  label="Attestation sur " name=" " onclick="{!c.checkAuraMethod}"  value=""/> 
            <div >  {!v.applicantSpaceTaskWrapper.capitalLemoine}&nbsp;{!$Label.c.CLV1_Euro}</div> 
            
        </div>
```

MY controller code below>

```
 checkAuraMethod: function(component, event, helper){
         Console.log('Checkbox clicked');
       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onchange` and `onclick` should both work (if you're interested in changes, use `onchange`), but your method will crash. `Console` is not valid in JavaScript, it's `console`. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so you must make sure you're always using the right case.